# Arithmetics is broken in Python?

Tags: python, python-2.7, math, arithmetic-expressions

When I do this calculation
`2*(5+5/(3+3))*3`
I get 30 in Python (2.7).
But what it seems is that `2*(5+5/(3+3))*3`is equal to `35`.
Can someone tell me why python gives me the answer of 30 instead of 35?
I've tested with JavaScript, Lua and Mac Calculator and they show me 35.

Why does Python calculate wrong?

http://ideone.com/yiFJxS

Comment: Interestingly, Python 3 yields 35 ...

Comment: `/` is always integer division in Python 2.

Comment: That's because `5/6` yields 0 in python 2 and everyone else evaluate it as a decimal output

Comment: @DanielRoseman: so what got fixed in Python 3? `/` forces its arguments into floats?

Comment: Note: it's python 2.7

Comment: No, but the *result* of dividing two integers in Python 3 is always a float. See https://docs.python.org/2/howto/pyporting.html#division

Comment: Okey, thank you. All I need is to change integers to float on division. Tnx.

Comment: `2*(5+5/float(3+3))*3` works. `5+5/(3+3)` is rounded down or seen as `int()`, it seems

Comment: Yes, Python 3 seems to assume its a float, Python 2 gives you an integer. 2*(5+5./(3+3))*3 results in 35.0. So it's probably best to check for possible integer division yourself and use floats there.

Comment: The Python 0, 1 and 2 division was deemed broken a long time ago. It has now been fixed in Python 3. Please switch to Python 3, which is the sanest solution, or otherwise use `from __future__ import division`

Comment: @DanielRoseman / is not always an integer division in Python 2. `//` OTOH always is a flooring division in both Python 2 and 3.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This happens because of the piece `5/(3 + 3)` which evalautes to 0. You need to use either of them as float.

Answer (score -2):

Always assume it's an issue with something you're doing rather than with an entire coding language!

It works fine for me in Python shell.  35 is the expected answer and 35 is what we get!  Most likely something on your end or a mis-type / you've miss-commented something out.  This is from copy pasting your code above.

edit:  Who is more likely to be wrong, an individual? Or the masses?  Occams razor.  In this case I assumed he was using 3 and not 2.7 which led to the correct assumption as it does work in 3.

Comment: If you always assume there's an issue with yourself, you'll never find bugs in the language.